# SAML SSO Integration in Microsoft Teams tab app

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, saml

I have a web application which supports SAML SSO. Therefore my app can integrate with Azure AD, so that users can automatically sign-in to my app with their Azure AD Accounts. My app also supports for SAML SSO integration, so Azure AD can be also easily integrated with mobile and desktop clients.

Now my requirement is to make same process in Microsoft Teams application. I have a Microsoft Teams tab application, and my clients want to integrate with Azure AD inside Microsoft Teams tab app. However, in order to do SSO in microsoft teams I need to make redirection to Identity Provider. When I try to redirect to microsoft from my app, I get the following errors :

**Teams desktop :**

Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

**Teams web :**

Refused to frame 'xxx' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Actually for these errors there is nothing to do for client side. Is there a way to integrate my app to Azure AD(or any app that supports SAML) inside teams?

Comment: Please have look into this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

Comment: did you get chance to check?